# I have to prove this inequality for an even polynomial.

Tags: inequality

[image]
I have done the cases for $x<0$ and $x>1$. But I have to prove this inequality for the case x belongs to $(0,1)$. I have to also ask if I replace the constant 1 by any positive constant will this inequality holds?

Comment: By the way—next time you ask a question, it’d be better to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than inserting an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just observe that, if $x \in (0,1)$, $x^4 > x^9$ and so $x^4 - x^9 > 0$.

Also, $x^{12} > 0$ and so to have $$x^{12} -x^9 + x^4 - x + 1> 0$$ we just need that $x < 1$, which it clearly is.

We have proven that this inequality holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and so you are correct in saying that if we replace the constant $1$ with any other constant $\geq 1$ it also holds. It will not necessarily hold for a positive constant less than one, though, because this would require $x^{12} -x^9 + x^4 - x \geq 0 \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is not true.

Comment: I missed the part x^4>x^9 for x belongs to (0,1). Thank you very much.

Comment: I think $x^5$ should be $x^4.$

Comment: @B.Goddard Oh yes, you are correct. I misread the handwriting.